# Elasticsearch. Range query for strings with dashes

Tags: search, elasticsearch, range

I'm using elasticsearch with data that have string-field with date values, like this:

`"2016-01-25 18:40:18.933"`

I'm trying to use range filter for getting values from date to date. For example:

```
    "query" : {
        "filtered" : {
            "query" : {
                "range" : {
                    "createdDate" : {
                        "gte": "2015-11-01", 
                        "lte": "2016-01-25"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
      }
    }
```

But results doesn't contain values with `"createdDate": "2015-12-14 20:28:23.557"`

If I use `"gte": "2015"` or `"gte": "2014-12-31"`, then values with `"createdDate": "2015-12-14"` will be included in the results.

What's wrong in my query?

Comment: Can you share the mapping of your `createdDate` field? `curl -XGET localhost:9200/index/_mapping`

Comment: `{ "documents": { "mappings": { "order": { "properties": {
... "createdDate": { "type": "string" }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to be able to run `range` queries on dates, you need to map  your field as a [`date` field](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/date.html), otherwise it won't work as you expect. In the mapping you shared, `createdDate` is a `string`. You need to wipe your index and create a new one with the proper mapping for the `createdDate` field, like this:

```
curl -XPOST localhost:9200/documents -d '{
   "mappings": {
      "order": {
         "properties": {
             "createdDate": {
                "type": "date"
             }
         }
      }
   }
}'
```

Then you can reindex your data and your `range` query will work as expected.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I have a problem with converting field to date, because elastic service supported by external team and not only me use this. So, it may be not simple. I thought elastic can range string fields (https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/_ranges.html#_ranges_on_strings) And it works in other fields, so why it's a problem in this field?

Comment: The `range` query works for string fields but all it is going to do is simply perform a "lexicographical" range (i.e. alphabetical order), i.e. it will not interpret the date. If you ever want to be able to filter on date ranges using this field, it has to be a `date` field.

Comment: And from point of view lexicographical range, string "2015-12-14" is not greater than string "2015-11-01"? I thought it compares strings char by char and "2015-1" is equals, but "2" greater than "1"

Comment: The problem here is that your string is also analyzed, so the string `2015-12-14 20:28:23.557` will be tokenized as the six following tokens, i.e. `2015`, `12`, `14`, `20`, `28` and `23.557`. Hence, the `range` doesn't run on the full string value but on those tokens.

Comment: Ok, thank you again! I'll try to convert field to date type.

Comment: Cool, glad I could help.